# System hang and got error 110 when usb device use for gadgetfs

Tags: usb

Using "http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/usb.c" program try to set up gadgetfs on Jetson TX2.

Update VID PID for Nvidia:
    *#define DRIVER_VENDOR_NUM 0x0955
    #define DRIVER_PRODUCT_NUM 0x7020*

Also update autoconfig function for Nvidia :

```
*/* Nvidia processors, high/full speed */
else if (stat (DEVNAME = "tegra-xudc", &statb) == 0) {
    HIGHSPEED = 1;
    device_desc.bcdDevice = __constant_cpu_to_le16 (0x0001);
    fs_source_desc.bEndpointAddress
    = hs_source_desc.bEndpointAddress
    = USB_DIR_IN | 1;
    EP_IN_NAME = "ep1in-bulk";
    fs_sink_desc.bEndpointAddress
    = hs_sink_desc.bEndpointAddress
    = USB_DIR_OUT | 2;
    EP_OUT_NAME = "ep2out-bulk";
    source_sink_intf.bNumEndpoints = 3;
    fs_status_desc.bEndpointAddress
    = hs_status_desc.bEndpointAddress
    = USB_DIR_IN | 3;
    EP_STATUS_NAME = "ep3in-int";
}*
```

After run program get output at Jetson TX2 terminal:

```
*/dev/gadget/musb_hdrc ep0 configured
serial="1.3"
** Thu Jan 1 05:19:27
CONNECT high speed
DISCONNECT
CONNECT high speed
SETUP 80.06 v0300 i0000 255*
```

Output log At Linux host PC is:

```
*usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-2: string descriptor 0 read error: -110
usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0955, idProduct=7020
usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 3-2: can't set config #2, error -110*
```

After debugging **usb.c** step by step find that program is stuck into function "handle_control". Get event of USB_REQ_GET_DESCRIPTOR then USB_DT_STRING is called but after "status = write (fd, buf, tmp);" Jetson TX2 is stuck and reboot.

What is the reason of Jetson TX2 stuck & getting error -110 response on host PC?

After searching related to error -110, we got two different errno.h.

One indicate 110 as :
    #define ESHUTDOWN 110 /* Can't send after socket shutdown */

Second file indicate 110 as :
    #define ETIMEDOUT 110 /* Connection timed out */

In both case there is common outcome which is communication between host and device is break because of some reason. So what can be issue for this connection is break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is bug in kernel source file related to gadgetfs. After patch that bug using below update usb communication for gadgetfs between device and host with bulk transfer type is working.

https://www.systutorials.com/linux-kernels/88555/usb-gadgetfs-fix-crash-caused-by-inadequate-synchronization-linux-4-4-92/

https://www.systutorials.com/linux-kernels/88554/usb-gadget-inode-c-fix-unbalanced-spin_lock-in-ep0_write-linux-4-4-92/